# Eslint exhaustive deps warning in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, use-effect

In the `useEffect` of the component below, I face an ***ESLint  exhaustive-deps warning :***

ESlint is telling me that I need to include `selectedJar` as a dependency, but when I do that the charts load quickly then they all disappear.

I can go on with my development because everything works, but I assume, based on the message from ESlint, that I am doing something wrong.

Can anyone advise me on how this code should actually look?

```js
const Stats: Page = () => {
  const [selectedJar, setSelectedJar] = useState("example"); 
  const [jarData, setJarData] = useState<JarChartData>({} as JarChartData);
  const router = useRouter();
  const jar: string = typeof(router.query.jar) === "string" ? router.query.jar : "";
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async (): Promise<void> => {
      setSelectedJar(jar);
      const jarData: JarChartData = await getJarData(selectedJar);
      setJarData(jarData);
    }
    getData();
  }, [jar]);
  return (
    <>
      something dope
    </>
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a potential bug here, in that you both call `setSelectedJar` and then use `selectedJar` in the same invocation. This isn't likely to do what you want; `selectedJar` is not guaranteed to have the updated value until the next render.

Reading your logic, it looks like you want the value you fetch to come from the router all the time, but default to `"example"` if there is no value in the router; if this is the case, there is no need for the `useState`. You can just fetch your jar data whenever the value from `router` changes, defaulting it to "example":

```js
  const router = useRouter();
  const [jarData, setJarData] = useState<JarChartData>({} as JarChartData);
  const jar: string = typeof(router.query.jar) === "string" ? router.query.jar : "example";
  useEffect(() => {
    getJarData(jar).then(data => setJarData(data));
  }, [jar, setJarData]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought the app was working fine and I was just asking this because I had an urge to understand it, turns out it started being buggy randomly and unexpectedly. I added this fix in and now it isn't buggy anymore! go figure :)

Comment: Also, with this format, ESLint is happy with just jar in the dependency array. Thanks again!